# Type alias for auto

Tags: c++, auto, type-alias

Is it possible to create a type alias for `auto`? I've tried both `using var = auto` and `typedef auto var`, and both throw an error that it's not allowed. So is there a way?

Comment: Don't. Code is predominantly meant to be read by other people. Creating your own idiosyncratic name for something, just because you like it better in *another* language, is going to make other C++ programmers less able to understand your program. It's almost always better to be idiomatic.

Comment: Downvote a question but not an idea guys. Write an answer if you want to address the idea.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, you are right. Though it's not suggested, but it's allowed

Comment: @arsdever It's true that you _can_ vote however you like. But the system works best if everybody follows the spirit of it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes I know. I didn't vote-down. My comment is to express my agreement with your comment. The question itself is a good idea I think and also it is a "nice to have" question.

Comment: @arsdever: 

Comment: @arsdever I didn't downvote, but I don't see much value in this question either: The OP has not done any research into what `auto` actually is in C++, or what it's supposed to do. This could even be used to justify the closing of this question. I agree, though, that it might be helpful to have this question around, if only to point other people to it who haven't done the research either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

**`auto` is not a type.**

It is a keyword that triggers type deduction.

For it to work, there needs to be some information for it to deduce from! That's why it works in a declaration with an initialiser.

If you really want to be able to write `var` in your code to get the same effect, like in (say) JavaScript, you could write a macro:

```
#define var auto
```

This will make the "word" `var` behave just like the "word" `auto`.

But please, please, please don't do that. It will only make your code harder to understand by C++ developers, without actually providing any tangible benefit to anybody in return.

Comment: I was just curious if it's possible w/o macro, would not use it anyway.